# OnOptionsItemSelected() not sending to new activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent Options = new Intent(this,
                Options.class);
        this.startActivity(Options);
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
```

My onOptionsItemSelected() is not sending me to the activity I set it to. It just kicks me back to the previous screen. No errors or anything, just kicks me back a screen? I've declared the Options.class in the manifest file as well.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Options.class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Options extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);
   }
}
```

main_screen.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
```

LogCat: Just sends me to the activity then kicks back right away

```
02-04 12:26:55.494: I/ActivityManager(150): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.app.test/.Options } from pid 7978
02-04 12:26:55.504: I/ActivityManager(150): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.app.test/.MainScreen (has extras) } from pid 7978
```

Comment: please add the logcat, the manifest, and the code for Option.class

Comment: `main_screen.xml` code would probably be most helpful, are you sure you have the IDs set correctly?

Comment: Can you post main_screen.xml ? Does your Activity extend  android.app.Activity or your own BaseActivity?

Comment: Does it goes inside your switch case??? print some message and inform

Comment: It is not relevant to the question, but I suggest you extend PreferenceActivity for settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like it doesnt go in to right catch block and runs default option.
Try that:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent Options = new Intent(this,
                Options.class);
        this.startActivity(Options);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

And if it doesn't work, put Log or toast or something to see if it goes in

```
 case R.id.menu_settings:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the same but without

```
case R.id.menu_settings:
    Intent Options = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Options.class);
    startActivity(Options);
        return true;
```

It works for me, I hope it help.